# Given an initially high concentration of CO2 and H2O, how efficient can I conceivably make a photosynthetic reaction?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, xenobiology, atmosphere, volcanoes

### I have been told that the high proportion of O<sub>2</sub> and CH<sub>4</sub> in my atmosphere are unsustainable unless constantly refreshed by an active process.

I would like to sustain the following atmospheric composition:

75.11% N<sub>2</sub>

22.04% O<sub>2</sub>

1.38% CH<sub>4</sub>

0.83% Ne

0.21% CO<sub>2</sub>

0.18% Xe

0.11% Ar

0.09% Kr

0.04% He

Molecular mass = 28.93

Rspecific = 287.38

Density at sea level = 1.08 kg/m<sup>3</sup>

Pressure at sea level = 0.81 atm

Scale height = 9717.35 m

### My question:

How efficient would my photosynthetic and other carbon sequestration processes need to be to maintain this equilibrium between O<sub>2</sub>, CH<sub>4</sub>, CO<sub>2</sub> and H<sub>2</sub>O? Keep in mind that it doesn't need to be perfect; My planet is highly geologically active and I can provide methane via volcanism (I think).

I'm trying to find examples of photosynthetic bacteria that produce a lot of methane as a byproduct of their metabolism, but nothing comes to mind right away. I'll edit it in if I find anything! I know at least if I can't find a cyanobacterium that does this, I can find a chemotrophic bacterium that does.

Comment: Gas with 75% $H_2O$ at 1.8 atm? Is it an ocean world? What temperature are we talking about?

Comment: Yes: my oceans cover 95.45% of my surface. I need to re-work this obviously, because as somebody pointed out, my temperature and pressure would condense my water vapor out of the atmosphere. (I'm a tunnel-visioned idiot)

Comment: Are you still looking for this question to be answered?

Comment: Suggestion: save link to this question, delete it and then when you will get back from your drawing board edit it and undelete.

Comment: Where all h2o went? On Earth it is 0.25% and that's a reasonable start for planet with ocean.

Comment: Just a note that volcanism might work but also methane vents and fissures occur independently of volcanoes, along plate boundaries - Mud pots in Azerbaijan, for example, and elsewhere. Presumably the geology of yellowstone has some good examples of methane sources, too.

Comment: @RúnatálAtlasThorn I've noticed that this is another in a relatively long series of questions about this specific planet. I'd recommend you remove the statistics about your planet from all your questions but one, and then link to that question. As a bonus, you'll get magic share points when people follow the links.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of an answer you expect. If you are looking for existing organisms this is off topic. What do you want to know by "how efficient"? This https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthetic_efficiency?wprov=sfla1 ? I don't see how this is answerable currently .

Answer (score 1):

interesting question.  What's the "purpose" of maintaining atmospheric methane in this scenario?

In the oceans, you're methanogens (if you like biological CH4 production in addition to volcanoes) will be in part canceled out by the methanogens who use the methane as a carbon and energy source in aerobic and anaerobic conditions.  The methane is a great, high density energy source.  Some of our earliest metabolisms harness it, mostly archaea.

I suppose if the environment were very simple, and the methanotrophs haven't yet evolved, methane concentrations would climb rapidly, leading to greater warming and allowing for the higher atmospheric water concentrations and pressure you mentioned.  A slice in time approach of evolution, ha.

Thanks, Colin